# Laptop goes to black screen or sleeps after Lubuntu 18.04 boot

Tags: boot, 18.04

I have a Toshiba Satellite M55 with Celeron M, old laptop. After installing any flavor of Ubuntu 18.04 and reboot and after the logo splash screen, the laptop seems go to sleep mode, power button slowly flashing. Or it's a black screen. After pressing the power button HDD and fan start but screen stays black. It only boot when an external monitor is connected. But once again to black screen if I boot without the external monitor connection.

Thank you in advance!